# How to use conditional setState and give that value to another component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working with React Native now, and I want to determine conditions inside of the setState. After that operation I want to give that value to another class and change the text inside of the that class.

Firstly, I want to determine and change the isLightOn value between true and false when I press to button.

Here is my codes:

```
class LightButton extends  Component {

    state = {
        isLightOn: false
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.red} >

                <LightBulb> </LightBulb>
          <Button
           title="Turn light on"
           onPress={() => { this.setState({isLightOn:true}) }}
          />
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

After that, I want to use that isLightOn value inside of the another class. According to that value there will some text changes off to on or on to off.

**Here is my second class:**

```
class LightBulb extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.green} >

                <Text> OFF </Text>

            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

How to change data with using setState() and pass thah data to another class?

Comment: It looks like you are facing 3 small problems: [How to toggle boolean state of react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40359800/1218980), [passing state value to a child component via props](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54795639/1218980) and [conditional rendering in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44046037/1218980)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your isLightOn state value use the following expression when the button is pressed:
`this.setState({isLightOn: !this.state.isLightOn})`

Then you need to pass the state to your LightBulb component.

In the end you should conditionally render your component:

```
class LightButton extends  Component {

    state = {
        isLightOn: false
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.red} >

                <LightBulb isLightOn={this.state.isLightOn}> </LightBulb>
          <Button
           title="Turn light on"
           onPress={() => { this.setState({isLightOn: !isLightOn}) }}
          />
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

```
class LightBulb extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <View style={this.props.isLightOn ? styles.green : styles.red} >

                {this.props.isLightOn 
                  ?
                    <Text> OFF </Text>
                  :
                    <Text> ON </Text>
                }

            </View>

        );
    }
}
```